# ComputeBuffer Values messed up when calling the dispatch many times in a row

Tags: unity, c#, shaders, hlsl, compute-shader

I'm having a `RWStructuredBuffer` called AffectedVertices give me random data instead of 1 simple value to `resultAffectedVertices`, when i get i run `SurfaceNets()` a lot by holding space.

The problem lies with my chunkGenerator compute shader's kernel, which, generate the base data into `vertices` for the other kernels that only read from `vertices` buffer.

this problem disappears if i add a breakpoint before and after running `SurfaceNets()` in order to have it only run 1 by 1

This is my code:
Chunk.compute

```
#include "simplex/noiseSimplex.cginc"


int vertMultiplier;
float element;

int octaveNumber;
float noiseFrequency;
float noiseAmplitude;
float noisePersistence;
float lac;

#pragma kernel CSMain


RWStructuredBuffer<float4> vertices;
float4 chunkCenterPos;
float3 sphereCenter;
float sphereRadius;

RWStructuredBuffer<float3> AffectedVertices;

float sNoiseLayered(float3 pos, int numL, float amp, float freq, float prs, float lac)
{
    float noiseSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numL; i ++)
    {
        noiseSum += snoise(pos * freq) * amp;
        amp *= prs;
        freq *= lac;
    }
    return noiseSum;
}

[numthreads(1,1,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{

    vertices[id.x + vertMultiplier* id.y + vertMultiplier*vertMultiplier*id.z] = float4(id.x,id.y,id.z,sNoiseLayered(float3(id.x + chunkCenterPos.x,id.y + chunkCenterPos.y,id.z + chunkCenterPos.z),octaveNumber,noiseAmplitude,noiseFrequency,noisePersistence,lac) ) ;//distance(id, float3(4.,4,4)) - 3.8     );
    if (id.x == 1 && id.z == 1 && id.y == 1)
    {
        AffectedVertices[AffectedVertices.IncrementCounter()] = id.xyz;
        vertices[id.x + vertMultiplier * id.y + vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier * id.z].w = distance(id, sphereCenter - chunkCenterPos)  - sphereRadius;
    }
}
```

````
void SurfaceNetting()
    {
        meshCollider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();


        chunkGenerator.SetInt("vertMultiplier", vertMultiplier);
        NetsSampler.SetInt("vertMultiplier", vertMultiplier);
        SurfaceNetter.SetInt("vertMultiplier", vertMultiplier);
        SNTriangler.SetInt("vertMultiplier", vertMultiplier);

        chunkGenerator.SetInt("octaveNumber", octaveNumber);
        chunkGenerator.SetFloat("noiseFrequency", noiseFrequency);
        chunkGenerator.SetFloat("noiseAmplitude", noiseAmplitude);
        chunkGenerator.SetFloat("noisePersistence", noisePersistence);
        chunkGenerator.SetFloat("lac", lac);

        chunkVertices = new ComputeBuffer(vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier, sizeof(float) * 4);
        AffectedVertices = new ComputeBuffer((vertMultiplier) * (vertMultiplier) * (vertMultiplier), sizeof(float) * 3, ComputeBufferType.Counter);
        netsX = new ComputeBuffer(vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier, sizeof(float) * 3);
        netsY = new ComputeBuffer(vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier, sizeof(float) * 3);
        netsZ = new ComputeBuffer(vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier, sizeof(float) * 3);

        XTriangleFaces = new ComputeBuffer(vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier, sizeof(uint));
        YTriangleFaces = new ComputeBuffer(vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier, sizeof(uint));
        ZTriangleFaces = new ComputeBuffer(vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier * vertMultiplier, sizeof(uint));
        FinalVertices = new ComputeBuffer((vertMultiplier - 1) * (vertMultiplier - 1) * (vertMultiplier - 1), sizeof(float) * 3, ComputeBufferType.Counter);
        vertMapper = new ComputeBuffer((vertMultiplier - 1) * (vertMultiplier - 1) * (vertMultiplier - 1), sizeof(uint));
        FinalTriangles = new ComputeBuffer(21750, sizeof(int) * 3, ComputeBufferType.Counter);

        netsX.SetCounterValue(0);
        netsY.SetCounterValue(0);
        netsZ.SetCounterValue(0);
        XTriangleFaces.SetCounterValue(0);
        YTriangleFaces.SetCounterValue(0);
        ZTriangleFaces.SetCounterValue(0);
        FinalVertices.SetCounterValue(0);
        AffectedVertices.SetCounterValue(0);
        vertMapper.SetCounterValue(0);
        FinalTriangles.SetCounterValue(0);

        chunkGenerator.SetBuffer(0, "AffectedVertices", AffectedVertices);
        chunkGenerator.SetBuffer(0, "vertices", chunkVertices);

        chunkGenerator.SetFloats( "chunkCenterPos", transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

        chunkGenerator.Dispatch(0, vertMultiplier, vertMultiplier, vertMultiplier);
        //actually when i check in unity i find 512 vertices on the mesh, but when i check ther data inside the buffer i find 



        NetsSampler.SetBuffer(0, "netsX", netsX);
        NetsSampler.SetBuffer(1, "netsZ", netsZ);
        NetsSampler.SetBuffer(2, "netsY", netsY);

        NetsSampler.SetBuffer(0, "vertices", chunkVertices);
        NetsSampler.SetBuffer(1, "vertices", chunkVertices);
        NetsSampler.SetBuffer(2, "vertices", chunkVertices);

        NetsSampler.SetBuffer(0, "XTriangleFaces", XTriangleFaces);
        NetsSampler.SetBuffer(1, "ZTriangleFaces", ZTriangleFaces);
        NetsSampler.SetBuffer(2, "YTriangleFaces", YTriangleFaces);

        NetsSampler.Dispatch(0, vertMultiplier, vertMultiplier, vertMultiplier);
        NetsSampler.Dispatch(1, vertMultiplier, vertMultiplier, vertMultiplier);
        NetsSampler.Dispatch(2, vertMultiplier, vertMultiplier, vertMultiplier);


        SurfaceNetter.SetBuffer(0, "FinalVertices", FinalVertices);

        SurfaceNetter.SetBuffer(0, "netsX", netsX);
        SurfaceNetter.SetBuffer(0, "netsY", netsY);
        SurfaceNetter.SetBuffer(0, "netsZ", netsZ);
        SurfaceNetter.SetBuffer(0, "vertMapper", vertMapper);

        SurfaceNetter.SetBuffer(0, "XTriangleFaces", XTriangleFaces);
        SurfaceNetter.SetBuffer(0, "ZTriangleFaces", ZTriangleFaces);
        SurfaceNetter.SetBuffer(0, "YTriangleFaces", YTriangleFaces);

        SurfaceNetter.Dispatch(0, (vertMultiplier - 1), (vertMultiplier - 1), (vertMultiplier - 1));

        SNTriangler.SetBuffer(0, "vertices", chunkVertices);
        SNTriangler.SetBuffer(0, "XTriangleFaces", XTriangleFaces);
        SNTriangler.SetBuffer(0, "ZTriangleFaces", ZTriangleFaces);
        SNTriangler.SetBuffer(0, "YTriangleFaces", YTriangleFaces);
        SNTriangler.SetBuffer(0, "FinalVertices", FinalVertices);
        SNTriangler.SetBuffer(0, "FinalTriangles", FinalTriangles);
        SNTriangler.SetBuffer(0, "vertMapper", vertMapper);


        //*
        SNTriangler.Dispatch(0, vertMultiplier, vertMultiplier, vertMultiplier);

        c = new Vector4[chunkVertices.count];

        chunkVertices.GetData(c);
        resultAffectedVertices = new Vector3[chunkVertices.count];
        AffectedVertices.GetData(resultAffectedVertices);

        //*/
        vertices = new Vector3[FinalVertices.count];
        FinalVertices.GetData(vertices);
        
        List<Vector3> vertices3 = new List<Vector3>();
        bool poi = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
            if (vertices[i] != Vector3.zero ) { vertices3.Add(vertices[i]); }
            else if (!poi) { vertices3.Add(vertices[i]); }
        Vector3[] vertices2 = new Vector3[vertices3.Count];
        vertices2 = vertices3.ToArray();

        tfx = new uint[XTriangleFaces.count];
        tfy = new uint[YTriangleFaces.count];
        tfz = new uint[ZTriangleFaces.count];

        /*XTriangleFaces.GetData(tfx);
        YTriangleFaces.GetData(tfy);
        ZTriangleFaces.GetData(tfz);*/


        triangles = new int[FinalTriangles.count];

        FinalTriangles.GetData(triangles);


        List<int> triangles3 = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length - 3; i += 3)
            if (triangles[i] == 0 && triangles[i + 1] == 0 && triangles[i + 2] == 0) { }
        else {triangles3.Add(triangles[i]); triangles3.Add(triangles[i+1]); triangles3.Add(triangles[i+2]); }
        int[] triangles2 = new int[triangles3.Count];
        triangles2 = triangles3.ToArray();

        NX = new Vector3[netsX.count];
        NY = new Vector3[netsY.count];
        NZ = new Vector3[netsZ.count];

        /*netsX.GetData(NX);
        netsY.GetData(NY);
        netsZ.GetData(NZ);*/

        //Debug.Log(vertices[2]);


        mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        mesh.vertices = vertices2;
        mesh.triangles = triangles2;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        mesh.RecalculateBounds();

        meshCollider.sharedMesh = mesh;

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        //meshCollider.convex = true;

         chunkVertices.Release();
         netsX.Release();
         netsY.Release();
         netsZ.Release();
         FinalVertices.Release();
         FinalTriangles.Release();
         XTriangleFaces.Release();
         YTriangleFaces.Release();
         ZTriangleFaces.Release();
         vertMapper.Release();

         AffectedVertices.Release();
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Please include any relevant code in the question itself, instead of providing links to external sites that could rot.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 sure, no problem